# Several Errors with GNE

Tags: c++, networking

While I am new to C++, (I have experience with Java) I am starting a project which requires the use of [GNE](http://www.gillius.org/gne/), or the Game Networking Engine.

In their [tutorial](http://www.gillius.org/gne/tutorials/tut1.htm#part1), (granted its from 2003) they use this line:

```
if ( initGNE( NL_IP, atexit ) ) {
```

in my code, I use the following:

```
log("Initializing GNE...");

if(initGNE(NL_IP, atexit)) {
    err("GNE failed to initialize!");
    err("Press ENTER to close MoServ...");
    std::cin.get();
    exit(0);
}

log("-> Registering game version...");
setGameInformation(myName(), myVer());
log("-> Initializing console...");
initConsole(false);
setTitle("MoServ");

log("GNE initialized!");
```

While compiling (with g++ on Linux, via eclipse /w CDT) I get the following errors:

```
/home/tehtros/Dev/MoServ/Debug/../src/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `GNE::initGNE(unsigned int, int (*)(void (*)()), int)'
/home/tehtros/Dev/MoServ/Debug/../src/main.cpp:46: undefined reference to `GNE::setGameInformation(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned int)'
/home/tehtros/Dev/MoServ/Debug/../src/main.cpp:48: undefined reference to `GNE::Console::initConsole(bool)'
/home/tehtros/Dev/MoServ/Debug/../src/main.cpp:49: undefined reference to `GNE::Console::setTitle(char const*)'
```

Note: In the documentation, they DID say that unless you first call GNE::initGNE(), all other GNE functions would have the "undefinied reference" error.

---

If I change:

```
if(initGNE(NL_IP, atexit)) {
```

to:

```
if(initGNE(NL_IP, atexit())) {
```

then I get the error:

```
../src/main.cpp:38:27: error: too few arguments to function ‘int atexit(void (*)())’
```

---

While this is nowhere in the documentation, if I change this:

```
if(initGNE(NL_IP, atexit())) {
```

even further, to this:

```
if(initGNE(NL_IP, atexit(shutdownGNE()))) {
```

then I get this error:

```
../src/main.cpp:38:40: error: invalid use of void expression
```

---

If I remove the parenthesis, like this:

```
if(initGNE(NL_IP, atexit(shutdownGNE))) {
```

then I get this error:

```
../src/main.cpp:38:39: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int (*)(void (*)())’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/local/include/gnelib/ObjectBrokerClient.h:120:15: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘bool GNE::initGNE(NLenum, int (*)(void (*)()), int)’ [-fpermissive]
```

---

As you can see, I'm a little lost. I can't tell if GNE is broken, if I am just making a small mistake, or if I just have absolutely no clue what I'm doing, and I should just stop trying to program something so big with my little understanding. (then again, I learn by actually doing, not by reading HOW to do.) Could anyone offer any help or support, and clarify what I am doing wrong, if anything?

---

Edit: I copied and pasted their example directly from their website, without any modifications, and it did not compile.

---

Solution: I resolved this issue by changing the order of the command. On the command line, I was able to compile like this:

```
g++ -o test "test.cpp" -lgnelib -lNL
```

To make this work with eclipse, I added `gnelib` and `NL` as libraries, and changed to build command to:

```
${COMMAND} ${INPUTS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${FLAGS}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are playing with the function point argument `atexit` but clearly it won't work if `initGNE()` expects a pointer to a function pass something different instead. In particular, it won't work to pass the `void` result of calling `atexit`.

The errors in your first example simply result from compiling the program but not linking with the appropriate library: you will need to specify the library where the functions are defined. Have a look, e.g., at the [installation tutorial](http://www.gillius.org/gne/tutorials/linuxinstall.htm) which shows that you need to use `-lgnelib`.

Comment: I tried to build a test program with:

g++ -o test -lgnelib -lNL "test.cpp"

where test.cpp is the example found at http://www.gillius.org/gne/tutorials/tut1.htm#part1

Comment: Yep. Won't work on UNIXes. On UNIXes the linker looks at the libraries identified by `-lgnelib` and `-lNL` and there is probably no symbol in there it needs resolved (the only candidate would be `main()`). Next `test.cpp` is encountered, compiled, yields plenty of undefined symbols and the linker goes on to the various implicit libraries, e.g., `-libstdc++`. Put your source file first and it will work. The command lines shown are obviously for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

While trying to fix the original problem you have gone into other issues, so let's focus on the original error. The compiler has completed processing your code, but the linker is not finding the symbols that you use. You need to link the library that contains those symbols into your executable.

Comment: When I built and installed GNE, it put the header files where they need to go. More specifically, gnelib.h and the gnelib/ directory are in /usr/local/include, which, according to eclipse, is already include by the system.

Comment: Plus, the GNE documentation says that all GNE function calls will be "undefined", until initGNE() is called.

Comment: @tehtros: Can you provide a link to where in the documentation they claim that? Trust me, a linker error cannot be resolved by calling a function... you need to *link* a library. What is your link line? (Or the compiler line if you are doing it in a single step?) The documentation most probably says that it is *undefined behavior* or that the result of any other function call will be *undefined* if you did not call `initGNE`, but that is completely different from the errors you are getting

Comment: http://www.gillius.org/gne/docs-0.75.0/namespaceGNE.html#97191c4b1dc10b38e685d91ec4741157

Comment: @tehtros: The documentation could use some work. I now see your confusion, but still an undefined error at compile (more precisely link) time is not what they are talking about there. Is the compiler complaining that it did not find `gnelib` or `libgnelib`?

Comment: I resolved this issue by changing the order of the command. On the command line, I was able to compile like this: g++ -o test "test.cpp" -lgnelib -lNL -- To make this work with eclipse, I added gnelib and NL as libraries, and changed to build command to: ${COMMAND} ${INPUTS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${FLAGS}

Comment: @tehtros: Besides accepting Dietmar's answer, you should also upvote it.